# Installing electron locally results in EACCESS error

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

installing electron on my mac results in the error below.

```
npm install electron@18.3.6 --save-dev

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/jestinevallendradwiputra/Desktop/twine-project/node_modules/electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/jestinevallendradwiputra/Library/Caches/electron/be7aa362da04885d3c6f0e315dab2845729abd2fa234bc9ef565b086c44e7876'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/jestinevallendradwiputra/.npm/_logs/2023-04-26T09_58_59_490Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried changing the node and npm version and it still doesn't work. I also tried

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`.

That doesn't work too. I'm currently on node `v16.16.0` and npm `v8.11.0`

if any of you know how to fix it, it'll be very helpful. Thank You

Comment: Run the cmd as administrator and check, could be privilage issue.